# check if variable is NA

Tags: null, pine-script

I use pine script and I want to check if some variable is NA.
Say:

```
float value = na

if value == na
   // do something
```

As far as I am aware, the manual says that it is not guaranteed to work.
Are there any alternatives to check if a variable is NA? I can't assign it to 0 though, since the outcome value can be 0.0 in my script.
I am new to Pine Script.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `na()` function :

```
if na(value)
     // do something
```